# Redis save to disk even after removing save configuration

Tags: java, redis

I have redis ( version 3.0.5) running as standalone server. Since i do not want redis to save data to file I commented out `save` parameters in `redis.conf` file ( then server restarted )

```
#save 900 1
#save 300 10
#save 60 10000
```

Even after the above configurations redis create `dump.rdb` file and following is extraction from log file which shows redis saving data to disk. How to disable this ?

```
1857:M 19 Nov 15:40:18.693 * The server is now ready to accept  connections on port 6379
1857:M 19 Nov 15:45:31.464 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
1857:M 19 Nov 15:45:31.465 * Background saving started by pid 3020
3020:C 19 Nov 15:45:41.311 * DB saved on disk
3020:C 19 Nov 15:45:41.320 * RDB: 24 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1857:M 19 Nov 15:45:41.398 * Background saving terminated with success
1857:M 19 Nov 15:46:42.002 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
1857:M 19 Nov 15:46:42.003 * Background saving started by pid 3490
3490:C 19 Nov 15:46:44.869 * DB saved on disk
3490:C 19 Nov 15:46:44.870 * RDB: 44 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
```

Comment: I saw this exact same issue yesterday on FreeBSD from source.

Comment: Perhaps you have a client issuing `BGSAVE`s?

Comment: I tried `./redis-server confile` to run the redis server and it seemed to resolve above problem.